# Chrome not displaying all list items with display:inline

Tags: html, css, list, google-chrome, anchor

So I have an unordered list with 7 items in it, they are displayed as inline and inside of the li there are empty anchor tags (I really need them to be empty and anchor tags).
Here's a link http://jsfiddle.net/FTHMf/2/.

Chrome only displays 6 of them, and I wonder why, firefox seems to display all 7.

Also, I don't want to use inline-block for various reasons.

Is there any way to fix this? What causes the problem?

Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<ul class="john">
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.john {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.john li {
    display:inline;
}
.john li a {
    background-color:green;
    line-height:0px;
    font-size:0px;
    padding:6px;
    margin:0px 2px 0px 2px;
}
```

Comment: I see 7 items on given fiddle - using latest Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the link now. That was the display:inline-block solution. Now it's the inline one which doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is not displaying the first element for whatever reason. Here is a that will not affect your HTML/layout in any way but beats me why is it happening - looks like a bug most definitely.

```
.john li:first-child a:after { position: absolute; content: ""; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/xW2e2/

Answer (score 0):

@user1128245 Use this

```
.john li {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to not use floats, as I've said , the problem is fixable but I'm just curious as to why chrome does this so I can avoid issues with it in the future.